# Embedding high-quality audio file on webpages without flash

Tags: html, audio, audio-player, soundmanager2, user-friendly

I am trying to embed audio files on a website for a client (who composes music as her job).

Since she is very specific about quality, she gave me a 20 minute mp3 track @ 320 Kbps (approx 50Mb). This track would ideally autoplay on the home page of the website when we arrive on the website, but have controls to pause it if needed.

There will be other players elsewhere (not on autoplay, though), so I need to find a way to do all this with the same look, in a way that I understand and that's simple to install (I'm not so good with JS). Also, I need it to work on all devices, no flash.

I first tried embedding with HTML5 (simple to use, no-flash), but the HTML5 player wouldn't start playing right away (or "stream"), it would wait for the 50Mb file to be fully loaded before playing, which took too long.

I also just tried to install the player "BAR-UI / Compact UI single Item" from [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/bar-ui/), it looked really good in its design, and would be ideal, but I cannot make it work or find a complete enough tutorial for installing a player with controls, even after trying for two hours - either the file doesn't play but the player shows up (although without song names displaying), or the song plays immediately in the browser, but the controls don't show. It's hard to troubleshoot SoundManager2 considering there are 4000 lines just in the CSS in their code, and I've found very few explanations to install SoundManager's Bar-UI and its very confusing files.
[WikiAudio](http://en.wikiaudio.org/SoundManager2:How_to_play_and_trigger_sound) has a great page about SoundManager, but it doesn't go into installing and displaying controls.

Other options I've looked at (jPlayer) were either extremely complex for what I'm trying to do (it's just a simple mp3 file playing as it loads on a website!), or were flash-based...

Answer (score 2):

To make the BAR-UI work in your webpage you must insert the HTML fragment. It can be customized with different class names (for example full-width for full width plauer):

```
<div class="sm2-bar-ui compact">
    <div class="bd sm2-main-controls">
        <div class="sm2-inline-texture"></div>
        <div class="sm2-inline-gradient"></div>
        <div class="sm2-inline-element sm2-button-element">
            <div class="sm2-button-bd">
                <a href="#play" class="sm2-inline-button play-pause">Play / pause</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sm2-inline-element sm2-inline-status">
            <div class="sm2-playlist">
                <div class="sm2-playlist-target">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sm2-progress">
                <div class="sm2-row">
                    <div class="sm2-inline-time">0:00</div>
                    <div class="sm2-progress-bd">
                        <div class="sm2-progress-track">
                            <div class="sm2-progress-bar"></div>
                            <div class="sm2-progress-ball"><div class="icon-overlay"></div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sm2-inline-duration">0:00</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sm2-inline-element sm2-button-element sm2-volume">
            <div class="sm2-button-bd">
                <span class="sm2-inline-button sm2-volume-control volume-shade"></span>
                <a href="#volume" class="sm2-inline-button sm2-volume-control">volume</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bd sm2-playlist-drawer sm2-element">
        <div class="sm2-inline-texture">
            <div class="sm2-box-shadow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sm2-playlist-wrapper">
            <ul class="sm2-playlist-bd">
                <li><a href="http://freshly-ground.com/data/audio/sm2/SonReal%20-%20I%20Tried.mp3"><b>SonReal</b> - I Tried</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you have to load the resources for the player:

- The JavaScript file that detects the previous HTML fragment and convert it to a player: bar-ui.js
- The CSS file to style the player: bar-ui.css

All these files are in the "demo" folder of the downloadable SoundManager 2: [download](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/download/soundmanagerv297a-20140901.zip)

Answer (score 0):

would Amazing Audio Player meet your needs? http://amazingaudioplayer.com/ they supply the js with some straightforward customization, and you can finetune the css for your needs.

I've used it successfully with 320kbs files, 12 minutes long.

Comment: It's a great tool I didn't know about, very customizable. Thank you. Nevertheless, I find the price for the version without the watermark and "free version" written on the player to be a bit steep (69$). Maybe I'll use the free version which is still a great improvement from the HTML5 code I had, and super easy to use.